# openmpi not working; no error message; only show warning message "hwloc/linux: Ignoring PCI device with non-16bit domain."

Tags: linux, configuration, mpi, environment, openmpi

I tried to use mpirun on my linux machine (Ubuntu 22.04LTS; linux kernel 5.14.0-1051-oem), however I only got a warning message:

> hwloc/linux: Ignoring PCI device with non-16bit domain.
> Pass --enable-32bits-pci-domain to configure to support such devices
> (warning: it would break the library ABI, don't enable unless really needed).

After showing the warning message, the program does not exit nor give error messages. Instead, I can only see a flashing text cursor and based on the hardware monitor, there is nothing running in the background.

The same issue would happen if I run hwloc-info/mpiexec.

I tried to reinstall the openmpi using `sudo apt-get -y autoremove --purge openmpi-bin` but it did not help.

The program I tried to run in parallel is OpenFoam, which can run perfectly without using mpirun/mpiexec

Comment: Can you compile from source and make sure that you don't enable hwloc? It looks like your mpi is complaining about a GPU or so.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you for the advice, but a reboot solved my problem. So I don't want to spend more time on this. This hwloc warning still shows every time I use mpi, so I guess hwloc has nothing to do with this problem.